# Tomcat start error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, java, tomcat

After running:

```
service tomcat start
```

I got:

```
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

After running: `systemctl status tomcat.service`

I get:

```
tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset:
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-12-13 16
  Process: 5177 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=217/US

Dec 13 16:05:15 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web App
Dec 13 16:05:15 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed s
Dec 13 16:05:15 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'e
lines 1-8/8 (END)
```

After running:  `sudo journalctl -xe -u tomcat`

I get:

```
 Unit tomcat.service has finished shutting down.
    Dec 14 15:51:02 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application
    Subject: Unit tomcat.service has begun start-up
    Defined-By: systemd
    Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up.
    Dec 14 15:51:02 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exite
    Dec 14 15:51:02 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web App
  -- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
  -- Defined-By: systemd
  -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

  -- Unit tomcat.service has failed.
  --
  -- The result is failed.
  Dec 14 15:51:02 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed s
  Dec 14 15:51:02 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'e
  Dec 14 15:51:07 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Service hold-off time
  Dec 14 15:51:07 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed to schedule re
  Dec 14 15:51:07 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed s
  Dec 14 15:51:07 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'r
  lines 3393-3415/3415 (END)
```

Comment: And where is the output of `journalctl -xe -u tomcat`?

Comment: Now I have added the output of `sudo journalctl -xe -u tomcat`.

Comment: It's imcomplete Dodmani!